# Загрузка файлов через API на сторонний сервис

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, multer

У меня есть SPA на Express.JS + React
Клиентская часть:

```
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState('');
  const [attachmentUrl, setAttachmentUrl] = useState('');
  const inputFileRef = useRef(null);

  const handleChangeFile = async (event) => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      formData.append('file', file);
      const { data } = await axios.post('/upload', formData);
      setAttachmentUrl(data.url);
      setFilename(data.name);
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        alert('Не удалось загрузить файл');
      }
    };
```

Серверная часть:

```
app.post('/upload', checkAuth, upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = req.file; // Получаем файл из запроса

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('filename', file);
    formData.append('access', 'false');
    const { data } = await axios.post('http://hdde.ru/api/upload.php', formData, {
      headers: {
        ...formData.getHeaders(),
      },
    });
    // Передаем нужные данные клиенту
    res.json({
      name: data.name, 
      url: data.link,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Ошибка при загрузке файла на сервер' });
  }
});
```

По документации сервиса сказано, что в поле filename (сам не знаю, почему так решили назвать ‍♂️) нужно передать сам файл.
Для примера и проверки, работает ли вообще сервис, сделал запрос через Insomnia согласно документации и получил такой вот объект в ответ:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 84,
        "url": "https://hdde.ru/file84",
        "link": "https://hdde.ru/files/hdde.ru_2192_1703156797.txt",
        "name": "Kods.txt",
        "opis": "",
        "type": "txt",
        "author": "User1352",
        "time": 1703156797
    },
    "success": true,
    "status": 200
}
```

Получаю такую ошибку в консоле при попытке загрузки файла:

```
[Warning] Jk (main.e50295b6.js, line 2)

code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"

config: {transitional: {silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}, adapter: ["xhr", "http"], transformRequest: Array, transformResponse: Array, timeout: 0, …}

message: "Request failed with status code 500"

name: "AxiosError"

request: XMLHttpRequest

listeners: {loadend: Array, abort: Array, error: Array, timeout: Array}

onabort: function()

onerror: function()

onload: null

onloadend: function()

onloadstart: null

onprogress: null

onreadystatechange: null

ontimeout: function()

readyState: 4

response: "{\"error\":\"Ошибка при загрузке файла на сервер\"}"

responseText: "{\"error\":\"Ошибка при загрузке файла на сервер\"}"

responseType: ""

responseURL: "http://test1.ru/upload"

responseXML: null

status: 500

statusText: "Internal Server Error"

timeout: 0

upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}

withCredentials: false

XMLHttpRequest (прототип)

response: Object

config: {transitional: {silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}, adapter: ["xhr", "http"], transformRequest: Array, transformResponse: Array, timeout: 0, …}

data: {error: "Ошибка при загрузке файла на сервер"}

headers: Rw {access-control-allow-origin: "*", connection: "keep-alive", content-length: "77", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", date: "Thu, 21 Dec 2023 14:45:40 GMT", …}

request: XMLHttpRequest

listeners: {loadend: Array, abort: Array, error: Array, timeout: Array}

onabort: function()

onerror: function()

onload: null

onloadend: function()

onloadstart: null

onprogress: null

onreadystatechange: null

ontimeout: function()

readyState: 4

response: "{\"error\":\"Ошибка при загрузке файла на сервер\"}"

responseText: "{\"error\":\"Ошибка при загрузке файла на сервер\"}"

responseType: ""

responseURL: "http://test1.ru/upload"

responseXML: null

status: 500

statusText: "Internal Server Error"

timeout: 0

upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}

withCredentials: false

XMLHttpRequest (прототип)

status: 500

statusText: "Internal Server Error"

Object (прототип)

stack: "Jk@http://test1.ru/static/js/main.e50295b6.js:2:1208522↵@http://test1.ru/static/js/main.e50295b6.js:2:122268…"

Jk (прототип)
```

Помогите дурному новичку, пожалуйста 
Уже все перепробовал, не могу понять, в чем проблема..

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки

Comment: @SwaD не знаю, правильно ли я Вас понял, но добавил

Comment: У вас на сервере есть `console.error(error)` - что туда попадает? Как я понимаю, 500 ошибку вы получаете как раз из блока catch. И так как вы делаете `const { data }` возможно, что `data.data.name` не существует, есть `data.name`

Comment: @SwaD, да, вы правы, это я Вам и скинул.

это все, что он пишет в консоль..


насчет data сейчас попробую

Comment: Т.к. `response: "{\"error\":\"Ошибка при загрузке файла на сервер\"}"` в коде сервера стоит в блоке катч и после консоли, то ошибка из вопроса, это то что приходит клиенту как ответ. Интересует, что пишется на самом серваке, если вы попали в catch